# Convert array to object in php - Convert this array to object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

Help me convert this array to object in php, below is my code

```
data: [
    [
        1638849672000,
        0.0025
    ],
    [
        1638849732000,
        0.0008
    ],
    [
        1638849792000,
        0
    ],
    [
        1638849852000,
        0
    ]
]
```

I want convert to Object

```
data: [
    {
        'time': 1638849670000,
        'value': 0.0025,
    },
    {
        'time': 1638849730000,
        'value': 0.0008,
    },
    {
        'time': 1638849790000,
        'value': 0.0,
    },
    {
        'time': 1638849850000,
        'value: 0.0,
    }
]
```

Here is my code

```
$newdata = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $vl) {
        array_push($newdata, [
            'time' => $vl,
            'value' => $vl
        ]);
    }
}
```

Help me convert this array to object in php, below is my code
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can just cast your array in object

```
$newData = (object) $data;
```

Or use the stdClass

```
$newData = new stdClass();
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $newData->$key = $value;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of objects, you could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$data = array_map(function($x) {
    return (object)[
        "time" => $x[0],
        "value" => $x[1]
    ];
}, $data);
```

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/uFBt5)

Answer (score 1):

You extremely don`t need nested foreach. You can use amazing built-in php function such as array_combine().

There are 3 options how to do that (can be more if you are creative person :D)

```
$keys = ['time', 'value'];

/** 1 option */
foreach($data as $value){
    $newData[] = array_combine($keys, $value);
}

/** 2 option */
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = array_combine($keys, $value);
}


/** 3 option */
$newData2 = array_map(function($value) use ($keys){
    return array_combine($keys, $value);
}, $data);
```

P.S By the way, php **supports associative arrays**. So, that`**s not an object**, it is an associative array (array with keys)

```
[
 [
   'key' => 'value'
 ] 
]
```